# Solaris 10 Default File Permissions

Tags: permissions, solaris

I've created an NFS mountpoint with rw permissions. How do I set new files in a directory to be created by a specific user/group with certain permissions?

Comment: You can use `setfacl`

Comment: setfacl is not working: 
testfile: failed to set acl entries
setacl error: Operation not applicable

Answer (score 0):

`chown` a file to any particular user/group that you need and then follow the below steps.

ACLs are applied to directories and files. You can't apply them to a group, at least not directly. You can apply them to all files/directories a group owns, by chaining with find:

```
find /home/username/filename -group «some-group» -type d -exec setfacl -m u:username:rx '{}' '+'
```

**References**

Please refer to derobert's answer to my old question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91510/setfacl-access-issues).